# How to write a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a executable "`myfile.exe`" file in location "`C:\Users\me\Desktop`" I want to execute a command "`myfile.exe <firstArg> <secondArg>`" at `C:\Users\me\Desktop` through batch file,

In command line:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>myfile.exe <firstArg> <secondArg>
```

How to write the batch script for the above command in windows

Answer (score 1):

With argument variables the contents of you batchFile.bat would be:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\me\Desktop\myfile.exe %1 %2
```

or with fixed arguments:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\me\Desktop\myfile.exe <firstArg> <secondArg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the exact command you are executing from command line to `.bat` file.
Change working directory first if necessary.

```
cd C:\Users\me\Desktop
myfile.exe <firstArg> <secondArg>
```

Comment: Or on one line: `%userprofile%\Desktop\myfile.exe <firstarg> <secondarg>`

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\myfile.exe %1 %2
```

Then you can call your batch file:

```
mybatchfile.bat <firstArg> <secondArg>
```

Also, you can use %* to pass all parameters rather than specifying each parameter.